# Build executable not found in the path defined in install_dir in meson build file

Tags: meson-build

I am creating a custom target which is an executable created from pyinstaller. I am able to see the executable in the project directory. However, when I add install_dir option, I should see it under /usr/local directory for ubuntu. But I am not able to see this. Can someone suggest what is the right way to achieve this?

```
bindir = get_option('prefix') + '/' + get_option('bindir')
spec_file = files([meson.current_source_dir() + '/pyinst.spec'])
custom_target('pyinstaller',      
      output : 'out_exe',                
      command: [pyinst, '-F', spec_file, '--clean'],
      install : false,
      install_dir : bindir,
      build_by_default: true
      )
```

Comment: Why do you have install=false, do you execute "$ meson install ?"

Comment: this is a custom target and I don't want it to be built before another executable that this target needs. It will be built when ninja -C build command is issued.